Find what depends on this job in slurm
Does slurm allow you to get info on reverse dependencies? By "reverse dependencies", I mean finding out what depends on a particular job, rather than what that job depends on.
For instance, Job A was submitted first. Jobs B, C, and D all depend on Job A. I know how to query for what Job B depends on and get the answer that it depends on Job A. I don't know how to query for what depends on Job A, and get the answer that Jobs B, C, and D all depend on Job A.
I've searched for this a bit in the slurm docs, but couldn't find the answer. My company is switching from LSF to SLURM, and in LSF we ran the following to get this info:
bjdepinfo -c ${jobId}
Thank you!
